# When did Russian officially replace Old Slavonic?

Tags: russia, language, latin-language, russian-revolution

When was Russian adopted as the official language of Russia?

*Background:*
Well into the XVIII-th (or even XIX-th) century Russian co-existed in a state of [diglossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia) with [Old Church Slavonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Church_Slavonic), based on a different Slavic dialect, codified in a written form in the IX-th century - the latter being used as the written language, whereas Russian was spoken in everyday life. (The situation is similar to the use of Latin and local languages in many western European countries in those times.) In XIX-th century Russian transforms into a modern literary language - the colloquial variety being complemented by words borrowed from other languages (notably from French), the dictionaries compiled, etc. (These developments are similar to [Luther's translation of the Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther_Bible) in the case of German or creation of texts like [Song of Roland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_of_Roland) for French.)

The question is then:
*When this modern variety of Russian was officially adopted OR/AND when the use of Old Church Slavonic for official purposes has ceased?* Has it happened before the Socialist Revolution of 1917? Or, if Old Church Slavonic never had any official status, when such a status was granted to Russian and what variety was explicitly specified?

**Remarks:**

- I am speaking about the adoption of a different official language, not just about [spelling reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_Russian_orthography)
- Related question in Linguistics community: [From Russian/Slavonic diglossia to modern Russian (via French/Russian?)](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/45698/27599)

**Update**
Now deleted answer contained some relevant information. In particular, Russian was singled out in [the constitution (*Fundamental laws*) of 1906](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Constitution_of_1906) (INTRODUCTION 3):

> 3. The Russian language is the common language of the state, and its use is compulsory in the army, in the navy
>    and in all state and public institutions. The use of local (regional) languages and dialects in state and public
>    institutions are determined by special legislation.

By that point the Russian was likely generally accepted as the only language outside of religious domain.

The answer also mentioned the Ukaz of Peter I, concerning the necessity to express oneself clearly and simply in official documents.

It remains unclear whether a) Old Church Slavonic ever had an official status, and b) whether the Russian government has ever made a conscious decision to switch from one language to  the other.

Comment: If it were a single event it would probably be under Peter I but I suspect it was a very gradual shift with no "official" date or document

Comment: @SPavel In other words, you suggest that no language had an official status until communist (or perhaps even post-communist) government promulgated a relevant law - at which point the question about choosing between Russian and Old Church Slavonic didn't pose itself anymore.

Comment: I would be shocked if the earliest law that says "Russian is the official language of Russia" didn't predate the 20th century. I just think that it recognized an existing hitherto unofficial state of affairs rather than mandating that the Russian language become universally adopted.

Comment: @cipricus I think there are two separate issues here: a) in which language the documents are actually written, and b) the law regarding the language in which they are expected to be written, as specifically mandated, e.g., but Constitutions/Foundation laws of many modern states (see [Official language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_language).) My formulation concerned the legal aspect. Actual language evolution is a matter of linguistics, and the question was asked there as such (the link is provided in the OP.)

Comment: The question should be focused on the language history of the official documents. What is the language of Ivan the Thirds's [Sudebnik of 1497](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudebnik_of_1497)? Was it Old Slavonic (which could fairly be called old Bulgarian), or was it Russian? (I personally don't know.) I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_literature#Early_history) that the `first work in colloquial Russian, the autobiography of the archpriest Avvakum, emerged only in the mid-17th century`. Official documents in Russian as such must be from Peter's time.

Comment: @cipricus see my answer to an earlier version of your comment above.

Comment: @RogerVadim - There must be some good source to give you as solid answer, but I don't have it yet. What is suggested in SPavel's comment (1906) seems probable.

Comment: I suggest a more explicit title of the Q: when has Russian officially replaced Old Slavonic?

Comment: @cipricus thanks, this is a good suggestion.

Comment: Why do we assume that such an official determination took place?

Comment: I am surprised no one has mentioned Pushkin yet

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Pushkin is implied, when I say * In XIX-th century Russian transforms into a modern literary language* - he played an important role in this transformation. But he had no direct influence on the official status of the language.

Comment: @MCW no assumptions are made in regard to the Slavonic: *Or, if Old Church Slavonic never had any official status, when such a status was granted to Russian and what variety was explicitly specified?* On the other hand, Russian has an official status today, and, as I have learned by now, has had it since at least 1906 (see the Update.)